# Possible to force printer setup (paper size) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, printing

I have a need to print pages from a web app on to 8" x 4" index cards. IE doesn't save print settings from one print to the next, so is there a way to programmatically force the print set up?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Look at this CSS3 examples from http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#size:

```
/* style sheet for "A4" printing */
@media print and (width: 21cm) and (height: 29.7cm) {
     @page {
        margin: 3cm;
     }
}

/* style sheet for "letter" printing */
@media print and (width: 8.5in) and (height: 11in) {
    @page {
        margin: 1in;
    }
}

/* A4 Landscape*/
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    margin: 10%;
}
```

Comment: 6 years too late, but the spec has finally caught up!

Comment: i am printing the receipt with POS printer, print is working fine, i am having trouble with size of paper its wasting a lot of paper with each receipt.
Need Help

Comment: @AmanDeep: if you have a problem then either find an existing question that covers it, or ask a new question. I doubt answer authors will be able to help you based on a brief description in a comment.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this in CSS using the [`@media print`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_mediatypes.asp) directive, no js required.  You'll have to calculate what sizes relate to a 4x8 index card and do all the positioning yourself, but it will work.  <del>Also, since this is CSS2 it won't work in IE6.</del> (see Joel's comments)

```
@media print {
  body {
    width: /*width of index card*/
    height: /*height of index card*/
  }
  /* etc */
}
```

Comment: Wait, what? I'm pretty sure I've used @media selectors successfully with IE 6 just fine in the past.

Comment: This page seems to indicate it works with IE as far back as version 4: http://www.codestyle.org/css/media/print-BrowserSummary.shtml

Comment: CSS supports inches as a unit of measurement for height and width as well... so 

@media print {
  body {
    width: 4in;
    height: 8in;
  }
  /* etc */
}

Should work fine, no>

Comment: Or, at least that it _can_ work that far back.  Some of the edge cases break down, even in later versions.  +1 anyway: using CSS is the right way to do this.

Comment: This won't force the paper size, but will print to a specified size, I think this is different. If you want to specify the page size, use the @page selector and the size attribute (CSS3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-size)

Comment: Right, we still need some interaction with the print dialog to make sure you pick the right paper size, once you have formatted for it.  Can we do that?