# Change the default browser print page size to A4

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

Is it possible to change the default print page size to A4, for all browsers?

Is there a JavaScript, or CSS declaration that will override the default size, and force the browser to print to A4?

IE seems to be set to print to 'Letter' page size by default. How can I override this, for visitors to my website?

I have set my CSS to the following, and IE doesn't adhere to the page size:

```
@page{
    size: A4 !important;
    margin: 18mm 15mm 8mm 15mm !important;
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to force printer setup (paper size) in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545849/possible-to-force-printer-setup-paper-size-in-javascript)

Comment: Print page size is usually set in the printer settings or operating system. Your little website shouldn't tell me what size paper to print on