# Set Paper size while printing via javascript

Tags: javascript, css, printing

Iam trying to print a pdf displayed in an iframe, I want the paper size to be A4 
How can i achive it,

Here obj is Iframe which is displaying PDF

```
            var wndw = obj.contentWindow;
            wndw.focus();
            wndw.print();
```

I tried CSS but its not setting the paper size. and i went through available SO questions but none of them are giving me a clear answer. Please help
Thanks in advance
This is the CSS iam using, I dont know if iam using it correctly

```
@media print and (width: 8.5in) and (height: 11in) {
    @page {
        margin: 1in;
    }
}
```

Here goes the HTML part , This is angular2 Component

```
<button *ngIf="ShowPrint" (click)="printDoc(fred)" class="btn btn-default pull-right" style="margin: 10px;" type="button" >Print</button>


               <iframe [src]="DocURL"  id="fred" #fred style="border: none;" height="100%" width="100%" media="print" >
               </iframe>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to force printer setup (paper size) in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545849/possible-to-force-printer-setup-paper-size-in-javascript)

Comment: you've not shown anything you tried, you say you tried something, but not HOW you actually tried - perhaps your CSS is completely wrong

Comment: i will add css now

Comment: Also, what is obj?

Comment: @JaromandaX here i have added CSS and the way iam using it. Please see if iam doing something wrong, Iam not much familiar with HTML CSS

Comment: `@media print and (width: 8.5in) and (height: 11in) {`  ahh, there's the problem - you want `A4` but giving `US Letter` dimensions - A4 is measured in the metric system, rather than rods and barleycorns

Comment: @JaromandaX its not taking A4 also, Its showing the previously printed paper size only.

Comment: How should i specify @media tag for Iframe ?? is this right way to do that ??