# javascript change paper size in print base on div size

Tags: javascript, html, printing

Is it possible to change paper size base on a div element ?

I tried to search it and i saw this 
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545849/possible-to-force-printer-setup-paper-size-in-javascript). But for me i need to change the size of the paper and do it in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

What is the use case exactly? As I have no info regarding your project now, I would only shoot some blanks on you, so it might not be really relevant (pls, provide more info to get more relevant answer) ... If you need to force some particular print layout for webpage, I would recommend converting the output to pdf with specified layout ... there are multiple JS tools for handling PDFs, such as [JSPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) or [PDF Make](http://pdfmake.org/) ... both can be optioned for specific paper sizes.

Comment: its for printing receipts. there are a function that user can configure the layout of the receipt including the paper size. so i need to get height and width of the paper base on the configured layout of the user.

Comment: So, you have user data inputs that you would like to put on print and you want user to decide what the size of the paper is and you have no problem of getting the user data and handle the inputs and the layout is also clear ... then as I wrote, just push the html layout containing the user data into pdf of selected size.