# Set custom page size in chrome preview dialog for print

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

i'm going to be as clearly as possible. I have a svg code (inside a div) that consist on an image and a text. I need that svg code to has special width and height; in particular, i need them to be 190 x 250 mm. I already set this, by assigning 925px to width (since i use an online conversor from mm to px) and 700px to height.

The problem is, that when i open the file on Chrome and proceed to print (Cmd + P), print dialog open, and it shows me that my design is going to be printed on a A4 page. I have a custom paper (in real life, physically) that has the dimensions previously commented, so thats why i need that, when i open the print dialog (cmd + p), the 190x250mm paper appears (and not the A4 which "adds" that blank space)

I have a Mac, and after the print dialog open, i'm able to click on something like "show more options", and then setting the paper size that i actually want. However, when i print with this, my design does not cover the 100% of the paper.

What i've already tried was, using jspdf library, convert my svg to a pdf with the exact dimensions that i want. This works, only if a use common fonts (arial, times new roman, etc) on the svg, but no if i use special fonts.

I really, really, appreciate some help here. Thank you so much, and sorry for my English. Hope you understand !

[This is my svg design - simplified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiAb3.png)

[This is what happen (and what i don't want to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DqPi.png)

**EDIT:**
This is what i want in order to be able to print (notice how the print preview "fits" to the custom paper size). (The image is edited of course)

[What i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd3XG.png)

Comment: You should add your svg code, and any other code you may have for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to force printer setup (paper size) in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545849/possible-to-force-printer-setup-paper-size-in-javascript)

Comment: Hi, thank both for your reply. I'm not sure if my code will help, its simple an image an a text with width 975 px and height 700 ! If you think it will, please tell me, and i will add it. @HereticMonkey, i've seen some of that responses and of course, try what they said. When i add things to modify the \@page, i didn't seen any changes on the size of paper that the print preview shows.  However, i'm thinking, that the changes are seen after send to print. Im not sure about this, and now, today, i'm unable to do a test (i dont have a printer right now).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a negative margin to the @page in order to remove the white border. But printers may decide they want that margin.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
svg{max-width:100vh;}

@media print{
  @page{
    margin:-1em;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
  }
  svg {
       margin:0;
       width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 100 60">
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="pink" />
  <text dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="30">TEXT</text>
</svg>
```

[image: This is the result I get]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. However i think you misunderstood  what i wanted to say (i don't blame you, my english sucks !). I add a new image of what i need. I don't want to set to 0 the margin of printers; and the white borders can easily be taken of by adding some *{margin:0}. In the example you send, the "big paper" is A4, i want to set that to a custom size.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I gather from your images that you are speaking Spanish. This is just to let you know that there is a [Spanish Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) where you can ask questions in Spanish.