# how to set defult print virew to A0 in window.print() using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have use 
var win1 = window.open("_new");
win1.document.write(`<title>'sheetName'</title>`);
win1.print();

currently A4 is default view opens how to set it to A0 by default using javascript

Comment: With the help of CSS you can set Page size for print media, but not if A0 can be set.
Refer : https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#size

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to force printer setup (paper size) in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545849/possible-to-force-printer-setup-paper-size-in-javascript)