# Set custom page size in print preview dialog

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

I'm editing an basic html file, which is to be printed from the browser. I need to have to page size be 8.2x12, a custom page size. I want to set this size in print preview, so I can see my changes to the file so that they are properly aligned. I tried setting a custom page size for print preview, but it only let's me pick a preset page size. How can I set a custom page size?

[print preview options chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDUuq.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to force printer setup (paper size) in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545849/possible-to-force-printer-setup-paper-size-in-javascript)

Comment: Haven't tried this myself before but see if [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#page-size) can help you. [Here](https://caniuse.com/css-paged-media) is some browser support info.